# Linear regression multiple output in python

Tags: regression, python, scipy, numpy

Say I have predictor array `x:(n,px)` and a predicted array `y:(n, py)`. What would be the best way in Python to calculate all regression coefficients (linear) from `x` to each dimension of `y` (`1...py`)? The output of the whole thing would be a matrix `(py, px)` (for each output, `px` parameters). I could easy iterate over output dimensions, however that would be inefficient as I will recalculate the pseudo inverse matrix of `x`. Is there any efficient implementation out there?

Comment: I am not familiar with python coding but could you use the formula $$\hat\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$$ in python?

Comment: Are you asking for how one would go about writing an OLS function, or are you looking for one (which has been answered below)?

Comment: @BabakP I don't think explicitly inverting $X'X$ comes remotely close to either 'best' or 'efficient' (as asked in the question). The two requirements are somewhat contradictory ('best' presumably including numerical accuracy/stability, which costs some efficiency and vice-versa) so some tradeoffs are involved, but if you invert $X'X$, you're not even close to the 'best/efficient' *efficient frontier*. Using something along the lines of a QR decomposition of $X$ is the standard approach... for generally good reasons.

Comment: Sure, but I didn't think I had to lay out all the steps.  If their taking the inverse I would hope they knew better than to try taking an inverse directly.

Comment: I think the poster is saying that there are multiple $y$s. numpy.linalg.lstsq can handle this task.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `sklearn` library in python, which (among others) implements Ordinary Least Squares Linear Regression

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Sample usage:

```
from sklearn import  linear_model

#creating a regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#runnin OLS on your data, assuming that you already have arrays x and y
regr.fit( x, y )

#displaying coefficients matrix
print regr.coef_
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even numpy has [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) which supports multi-variate output.